# ubuntu distribution upgrade got corrupted

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to upgrade the distribution of my ubuntu 11.10. The process got stuck in between. I restarted the PC, and when trying to run the dpkg command I get the error below -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for murtaza: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-common is not installed.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub-common; however:
  Package grub-common is not installed.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnih-dbus1:
 libnih-dbus1 depends on libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1); however:
  Version of libnih1 on system is 1.0.3-4ubuntu2.
dpkg: error processing libnih-dbus1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-common is not installed.
dpkg: error processing grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 libnih-dbus1
 grub2-common
```

Comment: Does the same problem happen if you restore from backup and try the upgrade again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't using `dpkg` to update the system, were you?!

Try recovering with `apt-get install -f`.