# error in upgrading ubuntu distribution

Tags: ubuntu

My ubuntu distribution upgrade got corrupted. As per suggestion from [ubuntu distribution upgrade got corrupted](https://serverfault.com/questions/491827/ubuntu-distribution-upgrade-got-collected)
I ran apt-get install -f to remedy the immediate problem.

Now while running do-release-upgrade -d I get the following error -

```
Upgrading
apport start/running
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Could not perform immediate configuration on 'passwd'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)

Could not install the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A 
recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a). 


Upgrade complete 

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade 
process. 

To continue please press [ENTER]
```

below is the error I get when I run apt-get dist-upgrade

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for murtaza: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-indicate-0.6 gir1.2-unity-4.0 gnome-about gnome-codec-install
  libdigest-sha1-perl libebook1.2-12 libecal1.2-10 libedataserver1.2-15
  libgail-3-common libgstfarsight0.10-0 libiodbc2 libperl5.12
  libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libtelepathy-farsight0 libunity-core-4.0-4 lzma
  mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-server-5.1
  mysql-server-core-5.1 python-farsight python-gobject-cairo python-papyon
  telepathy-butterfly
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  crda cryptsetup-bin cups-filters cups-pk-helper dconf-service dh-apparmor
  enchant folks-common fonts-droid fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one
  fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-liberation fonts-opensymbol
  fonts-takao-pgothic fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-kinnari
  fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-purisa
  fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typo
  fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-waree fonts-unfonts-core fuse gconf-service
  gconf-service-backend gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gudev-1.0
  gir1.2-indicate-0.7 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-unity-5.0 glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-icon-theme-full gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs icedtea-netx-common
  imagemagick-common indicator-applet-complete indicator-printers iw
  krb5-locales ktouch-data libapache-pom-java libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12
  libarchive12 libasn1-8-heimdal libatk-adaptor-schemas libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libattica0.3 libav-tools libbind9-80 libbison-dev
  libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libclass-factory-util-perl
  libclass-load-perl libclass-singleton-perl libclone-perl libcmis-0.2-0
  libcommons-cli-java libcommons-lang-java libcommons-parent-java
  libcryptsetup4 libcupsfilters1 libcurl3-nss libdata-optlist-perl
  libdatetime-format-builder-perl libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl
  libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdee-1.0-4 libdiscid0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2
  libdns81 libdrm-nouveau2 libebook-1.2-12 libecal-1.2-10
  libedataserver-1.2-15 libept1.4.12 libexiv2-11 libexttextcat-data
  libexttextcat0 libfarstream-0.1-0 libfl-dev libfolks-eds25 libfop-java
  libframe6 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-3-common libgdata1.9-cil
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgettextpo0 libgexiv2-1 libglew1.6 libglewmx1.6
  libgmime-2.6-0 libgmime2.6-cil libgnome-keyring-common libgnome2-bin
  libgoa-1.0-common libgrail5 libgssapi3-heimdal libgssdp-1.0-3
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgtkspell-3-0 libgupnp-1.0-4
  libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhunspell-1.3-0 libhx509-5-heimdal libicu48
  libidl-common libindicator3-7 libindicator7 libio-socket-inet6-perl libisc83
  libisccc80 libisccfg82 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libkdb5-6 libkdeclarative5 libkrb5-26-heimdal
  liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm3.0 liblockfile-bin liblwres80 liblzma5
  libmagickcore4 libmagickcore4-extra libmagickwand4 libmath-round-perl
  libminiupnpc8 libmodule-runtime-perl libmusicbrainz3-6 libmysqlclient18
  libnautilus-extension1a libnepomukdatamanagement4 libnepomuksync4
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
  libnux-2.0-0 libnux-2.0-common libodbc1 libopenal-data
  libpackage-deprecationmanager-perl libpackage-stash-perl
  libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-cap libpam-winbind
  libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validate-perl
  libperl5.14 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler19 libproxy1 libpulsedsp libqt4-help
  libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libquvi-scripts
  libquvi7 libraw5 librhythmbox-core5 libroken18-heimdal libsane-common
  libsocket6-perl libsonic0 libspandsp2 libsub-install-perl
  libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni
  libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni
  libtelepathy-farstream2 libtimezonemap1 libtry-tiny-perl libunity-core-5.0-5
  libunity9 libv4lconvert0 libv8-3.7.12.22 libvpx1 libvte-2.90-common
  libwacom-common libwacom2 libwildmidi-config libwind0-heimdal libx11-doc
  libx264-120 libxatracker1 libxcb-glx0 libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java
  libzvbi-common libzvbi0 linux-headers-3.2.0-39
  linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic-
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-sudoku gnomine unity-scope-musicstores
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice acl acpi-support acpid adduser adium-theme-ubuntu
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flashplugin aisleriot alacarte alien
  eclipse-platform eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp ed eject emacs-goodies-el
  emacs23-common emacsen-common empathy empathy-common eog espeak espeak-data
  evince evince-common evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-exchange evolution-indicator
  evolution-plugins evolution-webcal example-content exiv2 fakeroot ffmpeg
  file file-roller findutils firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
  firefox-locale-ar firefox-locale-en flex fontconfig fontconfig-config
  fonts-horai-umefont foo2zjs foomatic-db-compressed-ppds foomatic-filters fop
  friendly-recovery fuse-utils g++ g++-4.5 g++-4.6 gamin gawk gbrainy
  gcalctool gcc gcc-4.5 gcc-4.5-base gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base gcj-4.6-base
  gcj-4.6-jre-lib gconf-defaults-service gconf-editor gconf2 gconf2-common gdb
  gdm gedit gedit-common genisoimage geoclue geoip-database gettext
  gettext-base ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x gimp gimp-data ginn
  gir1.2-appindicator-0.1 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4
  gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7
  gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  gir1.2-wnck-3.0 git git-core git-gui git-man gitk gksu glib-networking
  gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop-data
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-doc-utils gnome-font-viewer
  gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-media
  gnome-menus gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-panel
  gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot
  gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra
  gnome-session-common gnome-session-fallback gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-system-tools gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnupg gpgv graphviz
  grep groff-base grub-gfxpayload-lists gs-cjk-resource
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
  gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-nice
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-tools
  gstreamer0.10-x gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf
  gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse gwibber
  gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica
  gwibber-service-twitter gzip hdparm hicolor-icon-theme hpijs hplip
  hplip-cups hplip-data htop hunspell-en-us hwdata hyphen-en-us ibus ibus-gtk
  ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-pinyin-db-android ibus-table icc-profiles-free
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-6-plugin icedtea-7-jre-jamvm
  icedtea-netx icedtea-plugin icedtea6-plugin icoutils ifupdown im-switch
  imagemagick indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime
  indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound
  indicator-status-provider-mc5 info initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
  initscripts inputattach insserv install-info intel-gpu-tools iproute
  iptables iputils-arping iputils-ping iputils-tracepath irqbalance
  isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes jarwrapper java-common
  java-wrappers jockey-common jockey-gtk junit kate-data katepart kbd
  kde-l10n-ar kde-l10n-engb kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdebase-runtime
  kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kerneloops-daemon
  keyboard-configuration klavaro klibc-utils krb5-multidev ktouch
  language-pack-ar language-pack-ar-base language-pack-en
  language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-ar language-pack-gnome-ar-base
  language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base language-pack-kde-ar
  language-pack-kde-ar-base language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-en-base
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome launchpad-integration lftp
  liba52-0.7.4 libaa1 libaccess-bridge-java libaccess-bridge-java-jni
  libaccountsservice0 libacl1 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapache2-mod-php5
  libapparmor-perl libapparmor1 libappindicator0.1-cil libappindicator1
  libappindicator3-1 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libapt-pkg-perl libart-2.0-2 libasound2 libasound2-plugins
  libaspell15 libass4 libatasmart4 libatk-adaptor libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libatkmm-1.6-1 libatm1 libatspi1.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libattr1 libaudio2
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7
  libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavahi-ui0
  libavalon-framework-java libavc1394-0 libavcodec-extra-53 libavdevice53
  libavfilter2 libavformat53 libavutil-extra-51 libbabl-0.0-0 libbamf0
  libbamf3-0 libbatik-java libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libbonobo2-0
  libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libboost-iostreams1.46.1 libboost-serialization1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1
  libbrlapi0.5 libbsd0 libbsf-java libburn4 libbz2-1.0 libc-ares-dev
  libc-ares2 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-perl libcairo2
  libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcanberra0
  libdlrestrictions1 libdpkg-perl libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a
  libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libdv4 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebackend-1.2-1
  libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libedit2
  libelf1 libemail-valid-perl libenchant1c2a libencode-locale-perl
  libequinox-osgi-java libespeak1 libev-dev libev4 libevemu1 libevent-2.0-5
  libevince3-3 libevolution libexempi3 libexif12 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev
  libfaac0 libfaad2 libffi6 libfftw3-3 libfile-desktopentry-perl
  libfile-listing-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflac8 libflite1
  libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libfuse2
  libgadu3 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgamin0 libgcc1 libgcj-bc
  libgcj-common libgcj12 libgck-1-0 libgconf2-4 libgcr-3-1 libgcrypt11
  libgd2-xpm libgdata-common libgdata13 libgdiplus libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdu-gtk0 libgdu0 libgee2 libgegl-0.0-0 libgeis1 libgeoclue0 libgeoip1
  libgif4 libgimp2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dev
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglade2-0 libglade2.0-cil libgladeui-1-11
  libglapi-mesa libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-cil
  libglib2.0-data libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgmp-dev
  libgmp10 libgmp3-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libgnome-bluetooth8
  libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-2-17 libgnome-desktop-3-2
  libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0
  libgnome-menu2 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd7 libgnomeui-0
  libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnutls26
  libgoa-1.0-0 libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgpgme11 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-l10n
  libgphoto2-port0 libgpm2 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgraph4 libgraphite3
  libgrip0 libgs9 libgs9-common libgsl0ldbl libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgtk-vnc-1.0-0 libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-cil libgtk2.0-common libgtkdatabox-0.9.1-1
  libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0
  libgtkhtml-editor-common libgtkhtml-editor0 libgtkhtml3.14-19
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell0 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common
  libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev-1.0-0 libgutenprint2 libgvc5 libgvnc-1.0-0
  libgvpr1 libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2
  libhogweed2 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-0 libical0
  libice-dev libice6 libicu-dev libicu4j-4.4-java libicu4j-java libidl0
  libidn11 libido-0.1-0 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35
  libimobiledevice2 libindicate-gtk3 libindicate0.1-cil libindicate5
  libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libio-pty-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
  libisofs6 libiw30 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper-java libjasper1 libjaxp1.3-java
  libjetty-java libjline-java libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libjpeg62
  libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjtidy-java libk5crypto3
  libkadm5clnt-mit8 libkadm5srv-mit8 libkate1 libkatepartinterfaces4
  libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5
  libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkeyutils1 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4
  libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libklibc libkmediaplayer4 libkms1
  libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpathsea5 libkpty4
  libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4
  liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1 liblaunchpad-integration-common
  liblaunchpad-integration1 liblaunchpad-integration1.0-cil liblcms1
  liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libllvm2.9
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblockfile1 liblouis-data liblouis2 liblqr-1-0
  libltdl-dev libltdl7 liblua5.1-0 liblucene2-java liblvm2app2.2 libm17n-0
  libmaa3 libmad0 libmagic1 libmeanwhile1 libmetacity-private0 libmimic0
  libmission-control-plugins0 libmjpegtools-1.9 libmng1 libmodplug1
  libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo2.0-cil
  libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib2.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil
  libmono-csharp4.0-cil libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west2.0-cil
  libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-management2.0-cil
  libmono-management4.0-cil libmono-posix2.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil
  libmono-security2.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip2.84-cil
  libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-sqlite4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil
  libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil libmono-system-web4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
  libmono-system2.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-web4.0-cil
  libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil libmount1 libmp3lame0 libmpc2 libmpfr4 libmpg123-0
  libplymouth2 libpng12-0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpopt0 libportaudio2 libpostproc52
  libppl-c4 libppl9 libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libpst4 libpth20 libpthread-stubs0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpurple-bin
  libpurple0 libpwl5 libpython2.7 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqt3-mt
  libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-network libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg
  libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtbamf1 libqtcore4 libqtdee2 libqtgui4
  libqtwebkit4 libquadmath0 libquicktime2 libraptor1 libraptor2-0 librasqal3
  libraw1394-11 librdf0 libreadline-gplv2-dev libreadline5 libreadline6
  librecode0 libregexp-java libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-emailmerge
  libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-l10n-ar
  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhino-java
  librpc-xml-perl librpm2 librpmbuild2 librpmio2 librpmsign0 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common librsync1 librtmp0 libruby1.8 libruby1.9.1 libsamplerate0
  libsane libsane-hpaio libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsaxon-java
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl1.2debian libselinux1 libsensors4 libsepol1
  libservlet2.4-java libservlet2.5-java libsgutils2-2 libshout3
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libslang2 libslf4j-java libslv2-9 libsm-dev libsm6
  libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsnmp-base libsnmp15 libsolid4 libsoprano4
  libsoundtouch0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspeechd2 libspeex1
  libspeexdsp1 libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libss2 libssh-4 libssh-dev
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl0.9.8 libssl1.0.0 libstartup-notification0
  libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.5-dev libstdc++6-4.6-dev libstreamanalyzer0
  libstreams0 libsub-name-perl libsvn1 libswitch-perl libswscale2
  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libt1-5 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtaglib2.0-cil
  libtalloc2 libtasn1-3 libtdb1 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2
  libterm-readkey-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtextcat-data libtextcat0 libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0
  libthreadweaver4 libtiff4 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5 libtool libtotem-plparser17
  libtotem0 libts-0.0-0 libtwolame0 libudev0 libunique-1.0-0 libunique-3.0-0
  libunistring0 libunity-2d-private0 libupower-glib1 liburi-perl libusb-0.1-4
  libusb-1.0-0 libusb-dev libusbmuxd1 libutouch-evemu1 libutouch-frame1
  libutouch-geis1 libutouch-grail1 libuuid-perl libuuid1 libv4l-0 libv8-dev
  libva1 libvirtodbc0 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvo-aacenc0
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvte-2.90-9
  libvte-common libvte9 libwavpack1 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common
  libwildmidi1 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common
  libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwww-perl libwxbase2.8-0
  libwxbase2.8-dev libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-dev libx11-6 libx11-data
  libx11-dev libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 libxalan2-java libxapian22 libxau-dev
  libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0
  libxcb-util0 libxcb1 libxcb1-dev libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp-dev
  libxdmcp6 libxerces2-java libxext-dev libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxml-commons-external-java
  libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml2 libxml2-dev libxml2-utils
  libxmlgraphics-commons-java libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxp6 libxpm4 libxrender1
  libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1 libxt-dev libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxvidcore4
  libxxf86vm1 libyajl1 libyaml-0-2 libyaml-dev libyelp0 libzbar0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 light-themes lightdm lintian linux-firmware linux-generic
  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-pae
  linux-image-generic linux-image-generic-pae linux-libc-dev linux-sound-base
  locales lockfile-progs login lsb-base lsb-release lsh-client lsh-utils lshw
  ltrace m17n-contrib m17n-db m4 make makedev man-db manpages manpages-dev
  php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql phpmyadmin pitivi
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript plymouth plymouth-label
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text pm-utils pnm2ppa
  po-debconf policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome policykit-desktop-privileges
  poppler-data poppler-utils postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1 pppconfig
  procps protobuf-compiler psmisc ptouch-driver pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf
  pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils pxljr pylint python python-all
  python-all-dbg python-all-dev python-appindicator python-apport python-apt
  python-apt-common python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon-gtk
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets python-brlapi
  python-cairo python-central python-chardet python-configglue python-crypto
  python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dateutil python-dbg python-dbus
  python-debian python-defer python-dev python-egenix-mxdatetime
  python-egenix-mxtools python-foolscap python-gconf python-gdbm python-glade2
  python-gmenu python-gnome2 python-gnomekeyring python-gnupginterface
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gst0.10 python-gtk2
  python-gtksourceview2 python-gtkspell python-httplib2 python-ibus
  python-imaging python-indicate python-keyring python-launchpad-integration
  python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri
  python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-logilab-astng python-logilab-common
  python-louis python-mako python-markupsafe python-minimal python-mysqldb
  python-notify python-oauth python-openssl python-pam python-pexpect
  python-piston-mini-client python-pkg-resources python-problem-report
  python-protobuf python-pyatspi python-pycurl python-pygoocanvas
  python-pyinotify python-pyorbit python-rdflib python-serial
  python-setuptools python-simplejson python-smbc python-software-properties
  python-speechd python-support python-telepathy python-tk python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web
  python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel
  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-virtkey python-vte
  python-wadllib python-webkit python-wnck python-wsgi-intercept
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion python-xapian python-xdg python-xkit
  python-zope.interface python2.7 python2.7-dbg python2.7-dev python2.7-doc
  python2.7-minimal qapt-batch qdbus qt-at-spi radeontool rake rastertosag-gdi
  readline-common recode rfkill rhino rpm rpm-common rpm2cpio rsync rsyslog
  rtkit ruby1.8 ruby1.8-dev ruby1.9.1 rubygems samba-common samba-common-bin
  sane-utils sat4j seahorse sessioninstaller shared-desktop-ontologies
  shared-mime-info shotwell simple-scan smbclient software-center
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk soprano-daemon
  sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher splix sqlite3 ssh-askpass-gnome
  ssl-cert subversion sudo synaptic syslinux syslinux-common
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev system-tools-backends sysv-rc sysvinit-utils tar
  tasksel tasksel-data tcl8.5 tcpdump telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze
  telepathy-idle telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger
  telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut thunderbird
  thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-ar
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us
  tk8.5 tomboy toshset totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins
  traceroute transmission-common transmission-gtk tsconf ttf-dejavu-core
  ttf-dejavu-extra ttf-droid ttf-kacst ttf-kacst-one ttf-khmeros-core ttf-lao
  ttf-liberation ttf-mscorefonts-installer ttf-opensymbol ttf-takao-pgothic
  ttf-thai-tlwg ttf-ubuntu-font-family ttf-unfonts-core ttf-wqy-microhei
  tzdata tzdata-java ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-docs ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-mono ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-restricted-extras
  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers
  ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel
  ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer udev udisks
  ufw unattended-upgrades unity unity-2d unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel
  unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-greeter
  unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music
  unity-place-applications unity-place-files unity-services unixodbc
  unixodbc-dev uno-libs3 update-inetd update-manager update-manager-core
  update-notifier-common upower upstart ure ureadahead usb-creator-common
  usb-creator-gtk usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd usbutils
  util-linux uuid-runtime vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny vinagre vino
  virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
  wamerican wbritish wget whiptail whois winbind winetricks wireless-crda
  wireless-tools wodim wpasupplicant wvdial wx2.8-headers x11-apps x11-common
  x11-session-utils x11-utils x11proto-input-dev xdg-user-dirs
  xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xfonts-encodings xinput xkb-data xorg
  xorg-sgml-doctools xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xserver-common
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-apm
  xserver-xorg-video-ark xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-chips
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-geode
  xserver-xorg-video-i128 xserver-xorg-video-i740 xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-rendition xserver-xorg-video-s3
  xserver-xorg-video-s3virge xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-tseng xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
  xserver-xorg-video-voodoo xsltproc xterm xul-ext-ubufox xz-utils yelp
  yelp-xsl youtube-dl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity
  zenity-common zlib1g zlib1g-dev
1726 upgraded, 283 newly installed, 24 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,524 MB of archives.
After this operation, 355 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'passwd'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

That thing is nicely hiding all errors. Try the old fashioned way by changing your sources.list and doing apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: Dennis thanks for the answer. I am sorry I didnt understand what you meany by 'changing your sources.list'. I tried running apt-get dist-upgrade and got the following error - E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'passwd'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)

Comment: That's not the full error you get. Please give all output.

Comment: Dennis I have added the complete output, appreciate your help.

Comment: ok, this is a tricky one then, even apt doesn't say much. Some interactive debugging is probably better than serverfault comments. Could you use irc, maybe via webchat.freenode.net if you don't have an irc client. I'm Seveas on freenode.

Comment: And if you can't join IRC, try this command: apt-get install passwd. That should updgrade only passwd and its dependencies, hopefully not failing or failing more informatively.